# How to Log AWSRequestId with Micronaut Lambda Application Native Image

Tags: aws-lambda, micronaut, micronaut-aws

Based on this [guide](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aws/latest/guide/#mdc) about logging AWSRequestId, I can add `%X{AWSRequestId}` on my logback.xml to print the request id on my lambda function.
On the example, the method that adds this key on MDC is `populateMappingDiagnosticContextValues` of class `MicronautRequestHandler`. But since my lambda function has two endpoints, I created it as an Application type and it says it's using the `MicronautLambdaHandler` as the handler class.
[image: guide]

What I did is I created my custom handler that extends the `MicronautLambdaHandler` and added the `populateMappingDiagnosticContextValues` method.

```
@Override
public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(AwsProxyRequest input, Context context) {
    if (context != null) {
        populateMappingDiagnosticContextValues(context);
    }
    return handler.proxy(input, context);
}
```

logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <withJansi>false</withJansi>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %X{AWSRequestId} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

On the lambda setup I pointed the handler on my custom handler and the app is working.
Except that the logs is not showing the AWSRequestId.
Is this functionality only works on `MicronautRequestHandler` class and not on `MicronautLambdaHandler`?

I also tried the aws [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html) here that uses log4j2 for logging the request id. But log4j doesn't work when building the GraalVM native image, that's why I sticked to logback.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied `populateMappingDiagnosticContextValues` and `mdcput` into your Handler (I suppose you did it) it should work without any additional changes.